# Eigenvalue of a Sum of Operator

Tags: linear-algebra

I am being a little less formal in mathematical formalisms and concerns mostly to Quantum Mechanics. The question is when I express a linear operator as a sum of two different operators , for example A = B + C , then whether it is possible to have eigenvectors of operator A ,even when operators B and C do not commute in general.

In quantum mechanics the Hamiltonian operator (H) is expressed as the sum of (P^2) the (where P is momentum operator) and V(x)(the potential operator). Even for the simple case of linear harmonic oscillator the V(x)= (1/2)k(x)^2 , thus it is for sure that the Hamiltonian is composed of two operators that do not commute to each other , yet we are interested in finding an eigenvector of the Hamiltonian , which requires the state-vector to be eigen vector to both the (P^2) operator and the (V(x) = 1/2k(x^2)) operator.

All operators and vectors are resident of Hilbert space.I am sorry if I am missing out any formality of vector spaces.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I think you are wrong in thinking that an eigenvector of $B+C$ needs to be a common eigenvector of $B$ and $C$. This is usually not true.

Answer (score 2):

A state can be an eigenstate of $A$ without being an eigenstate of either of $B$ or $C$.

As a simple example, consider 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is an eigenvector of $A$ but not of $B$ and not of $C$. More convoluted examples where $B$ and $C$ don't commute do exist. In fact, I think it would be difficult to come up with something that was *not* an example: Take any $B$ and $C$ that have no eigenvectors in common. Then their sum still has eigenvectors, as any matrix does.

In infinite dimensions it's not *that* simple, as not every operator has eigenstates (consider differentiation on the space of polynomials), but assuming everything is Hermitian (as one often does in quantum mechanics), it actually is that simple.